# How do I find the deployed contract address for CryptKitties?

Tags: etherscan

I read some version of the CryptoKitties source code on https://github.com/axiomzen/cryptokitties-bounty

How do I use information only on https://cryptokitties.co, and preferably inside MetaMask, to determine the actual address of the deployed `KittyCore` contract.

To be clear, some blogger has told be that this is what I am looking for: https://etherscan.io/address/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d#code However anybody could have deployed that. I am looking to determine which one is actually running behind https://cryptokitties.co.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've actually interacted with their DApp, yet. You can look up your ETH address & look at your transaction history or look up the transaction hash via etherscan.io. This will lead you to the "correct" `CryptoKittiesCore` deployed smart contract.

Which I've checked with ETH address & transactions, and it matches the URL you provided.

Or

Before you accept and submit a transaction via MetaMask, you can copy the destination address and look that up via etherscan.io to verify the destination.

Attempting to buy a kitty leads to this address: `CryptoKittiesSalesAuction`
https://etherscan.io/address/0xb1690C08E213a35Ed9bAb7B318DE14420FB57d8C

EDIT:
To further verify that `CryptoKittiesCore` is indeed that address you listed, we both have verified where the funds get sent to: `CryptoKittiesSalesAuction`.

https://etherscan.io/address/0xb1690c08e213a35ed9bab7b318de14420fb57d8c#readContract

Go to `Read Smart Contract` and look down at line item 9:

```
9.  nonFungibleContract    0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d address
```

This proves what you've asked.

Comment: I attempted to buy a kitty and MetaMask was about to send to: https://etherscan.io/address/0xb1690c08e213a35ed9bab7b318de14420fb57d8c I see how that confirms where I am sending money to.

Comment: But how do I use that knowledge to confirm https://etherscan.io/address/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d is correct?

Comment: Or are you saying you have interacted with their DApp?

Comment: Updating my answer. See Edit. :)